# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i got this error while running this code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
labels = ['a','b','c']
my_list = [10,20,30]
arr = np.array(my_list)
d = {'a':10,'b':20,'c':30}
pd.series(data = my_list)
```

full error msg

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-494578c29940> in <module>
----> 1 pd.series(data = my_list)

F:\New folder (8)\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    260             return _SparseArray
    261 
--> 262         raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    263 
    264 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'
```

Comment: Try "pd.Series". Capital S

Comment: ok i didnt expect it to be so simple thank you so much

Comment: If this comment solved the problem for you feel free to post the solution and accept your answer so we can know that your issue has been solved! See this Stack Overflow help article on [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`Series` is a Pandas class, so it starts with a capital letter. The below should work.

```
pd.Series(data = my_list)
```